# Storing json data in python

Tags: python, json

Is there a way to easily store `json` data in a variable in python. I don't mean the entire `json` in a variable, rather parsing and storing it as a key-value.

For instance - if this is the `json` file

```
[
   [
      1,
      "Apple"
   ],
   [
      2,
      "Orange"
   ],
   [
      3,
      "Grapes"
   ],
   [
      4,
      "Banana"
   ],
   [
      5,
      "Mango"
   ]
]
```

I want to have a list or some other datatype in python through which I can easily access the data.

Something like `variable[1]` should print Apple and so on

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You can use the `json` module. Specifically `json.loads`. However, if you also want a key value association between your data, you'll need to use a dictionary:

```
from json import loads

json_data = \
"""
[
    [1, "Apple"],
    [2, "Orange"],
    [3, "Grapes"],
    [4, "Banana"],
    [5, "Mango"]
]
"""

data = dict(loads(json_data))
print(data)
# {1: u'Apple', 2: u'Orange', 3: u'Grapes', 4: u'Banana', 5: u'Mango'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unsurprisingly, you need the `json` module.

```
In [29]: import json

In [30]: data = '''[
    ...:    [
    ...:       1,
    ...:       "Apple"
    ...:    ],
    ...:    [
    ...:       2,
    ...:       "Orange"
    ...:    ],
    ...:    [
    ...:       3,
    ...:       "Grapes"
    ...:    ],
    ...:    [
    ...:       4,
    ...:       "Banana"
    ...:    ],
    ...:    [
    ...:       5,
    ...:       "Mango"
    ...:    ]
    ...: ]'''

In [31]: json.loads(data)
Out[31]: [[1, 'Apple'], [2, 'Orange'], [3, 'Grapes'], [4, 'Banana'], [5, 'Mango']]
```

The module also contains functions to handle data in files.

To extract the fruit names by numerical key could be done in several ways, but they all involve transforming the data further. For example:

```
In [32]: fruits = []

In [33]: for key, name in json.loads(data):
    ...:     fruits.append(name)
    ...:

In [34]: fruits[0]
Out[34]: 'Apple'
```

Here Python's zero-based indexing slightly defeats the value of this solution given that the keys start with 1. A dictionary gives you exactly what you need. If you call the `dict` constructor with a list of pairs it will treat them as key, value pairs.

```
In [35]: fruits = dict(json.loads(data))

In [36]: fruits[1]
Out[36]: 'Apple'
```